# java modify non-static arraylist from another class

Tags: java

I want to use static methods on my ArrayList from another class. what should I do besides making the ArrayList sprites static. Since Ｉ need multiple instances of sprites later;

```
public class World {
ArrayList<Sprite> sprites;
public World(int level) {
    sprites = Loader.loadSprites("res/levels/"+level+".lvl");
    sprites.add(Loader.createSprite("player", 333, 222));

}


public class Stone {
World.sprites.add(Loader.createSprite("player", 333, 222));
}
```

like when I use spirtes.add in the World class it is fine but in the Stone class, it throws me a error Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field World.sprites. Why is that so ?

Comment: use object_name.array_list or you can use getter and setter method

Comment: make it static?  But as you say you need multiple instances then it can't be static.  So why not get have a method in `World` that allows you access to the list (like a getter) ?

Comment: You should avoid to declare things static, unless you really need to. What you need is to create an instance of `World` and work on it from your `Stone` class. Are you familiar with the [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) pattern? It is probably what you need

Comment: "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field World.sprites", because the `sprites` field in the World class is not declared *static*.  You should do a quick look up on the meaning of static. Read [here](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/static-variable/) for example.  You will either need to pass an instance of the World object to the Stone object, or use the Singleton pattern as Oneiros said. (Or design a centralized data object where you can retrieve specific object instances of different classes.)